# Require CSS code for dynamic menu active and inactive which is picking data from database

Tags: jquery, html, css, oracle11g

I have tried a lot for making my piece of code on menu design which picks data from database based on main menu which is selected that i would like to make active and inactive of tabs.

I have a table structure which contains data as follows

```
Main    Level1  level2
menu1   sub-menu1   ssmenu1
menu1   sub-menu1   ssmenu2
menu1   sub-menu1   ssmenu3
menu1   sub-menu2   
menu1   sub-menu3   ssmenu1
menu1   sub-menu3   ssmenu2
menu1   sub-menu3   ssmenu3
menu1   sub-menu4   
menu2   sub-menu1   ssmenu1
menu2   sub-menu1   ssmenu2
menu2   sub-menu1   ssmenu3
menu2   sub-menu2   
menu2   sub-menu3   ssmenu1
menu2   sub-menu3   ssmenu2
menu2   sub-menu3   ssmenu3
menu2   sub-menu4
```

Here when user clicks on menu1 respective level1 data has to be displayed in the form of tab and when user clicks on sub-menu3 respective level2 has to be displayed. This part is working fine by using queries. But i would like to give that respective tab is in active state as the user pressed on that tab.

My code works fine if it is static tabs. But as am picking data from database it is not showing active and inactive tab.

My CSS code for button

```
.Black .button .active-tab{
color:#000;
background: #dedede;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dedede 0%, #fff 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#dedede), color-stop(100%,#fff));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dedede 0%,#fff 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #dedede 0%,#fff 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #dedede 0%,#fff 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#dedede', endColorstr='#fff',GradientType=0 );
background: linear-gradient(top, #dedede 0%,#fff 100%);
}
```

Can any one suggest me how to do that and what type of code has to be written to show that respective tab is active.

Thanks a ton advance.

Comment: Do you assign the css classes to the tabs? How?

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle?

Comment: Sample fiddle show skeleton of UI Java code is not there http://fiddle.jshell.net/8SuLK/5/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to be honest, I'm not really sure what's your final goal but if it's just about getting the id or the href attribute of a clicked menu item then this should help:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/8SuLK/9/

Here is the jQuery Code:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    console.log($(this));
    var hiddenInput  = $(this).children('a').attr("id");
    alert("Value "+hiddenInput);
});
```

If you also need the href attribute you can get it simply by:

```
$(this).children('a').attr("href");
```

You can redirect with:

```
window.location.href="your_link";
```

But I guess you just needed the id to filter for the menu item above. In that case you got it and can select the menu item with a substring or something and add a css class. But if that's not what you want I could need further explanations ;)